# What form must a function $f$ have if $f(f(x)) = f$ and $f$ is differentiable?

Tags: calculus, analysis

If $f : [0,\infty) \to [0,\infty)$ is such that,

- $f(f(x)) = f(x)$,
- $f$ is differentiable,

is it true that $f$ is either a constant or $f = x$?

I think so anyway.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  If $f(x)=x$, we don't generally have $f(x)^2=f(x)$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner I think they might mean $f(f(x))$ but extra clarification  would be nice.

Comment: I think the OP means $f\circ f$

Comment: Oops. I meant (f•f) (x) =  f(x)... .

Comment: I can't quite tell what you mean in your most recent comment since I have become so accustomed to seeing things written in [MathJax and $\LaTeX$](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).  Can you confirm *with words* whether you mean for $f^2$ to be interpreted as $f$ composed with $f$? (*commonly written with an open circle $\circ$*)  Or do you mean for $f^2$ to be interpreted as $f$ *multiplied* by $f$? (*commonly written with a small dot $\cdot$*)  What you wrote it looks more like a bullet point than either of these.

Comment: See also [Find examples of continuous functions $f:[0,1]\to[0,1]$ that satisfy $\forall x\in[0,1], f(f(x))=f(x)$ other than $f(x)=x$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/949284/find-examples-of-continuous-functions-f0-1-to0-1-that-satisfy-forall-x).

Comment: See also [$f(f(x))=f(x)$ question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/681692/ffx-fx-question) and [Describe all the continuous function $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ such that $f \circ f=f$. Again describe all linear maps with the same property.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3328035/describe-all-the-continuous-function-f-mathbb-r-to-mathbb-r-such-that-f-c).

Comment: This question requires that $f$ be differentiable though, so I don't see that it's a duplicate.

Comment: I think the condition of differentiability is more restrictive than just continuity.

Comment: It will in fact force f(x) to be x on the whole of [0,infinity), assuming there are at least two points along the x-axis which do not map to the same point on the y-axis.